# Is there any way to temporarily stop fastDDS from sending or receiving topic messages?

Tags: data-distribution-service

In some scenarios, we need to temporarily pause the topic-based message sending and receiving of DDS, and then resume it when needed, does Fast-DDS have such a mechanism?